# react redirect to another page after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to another page after a successful login. After I am getting the following error.

[image: Error code]

[image: Error]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and error text as formatted snippets ***in*** your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are breaking the rules of hooks. The error is that you call `useHistory` within the function, they can only be called from functional component bodies and other react hooks. `Login` is a class-based component so it needs to either receive [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) by being rendered directly by a `Route`, or be wrapped in the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

Easy for sure solution is to use the `withRouter` HOC. This injects the route props.

If you want to truly redirect then I also suggest using `history.replace` so if the user later hits the back button or does a back navigation they don't hit your login component again.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  ...

  responseGoogle = (response) => {
    ...
    this.props.history.replace("/admin/dashboard"); // <-- access history from props
  };

  ...
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Answer (score 2):

useHistory didn't work on class component.its for Functional component.You need to use withRouter or from the props.You can refer this doc for more https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter.  https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

responseGoogle = (response) => {
    return <Redirect to='/admin/dashboard'/>
};
```

Comment: This isn't how renderable UI is done in React. You can't return JSX from a callback and expect it to just be rendered.

Comment: Yes, but for a functional component this will work

Comment: Sorry, not even for a functional component would this work. All renderable JSX has to be returned from the `render` lifecycle function, or the return from the ***body*** of a functional component. Functional components are not even a part of this question.